# How to Evaluate using "groovy.util.Eval" class

Tags: java, groovy

I am unable to evaluate the following statement in groovy:

```
def responseAct = new JsonSlurper().parseText(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(Step).getPropertyValue("response"));
String x = "response.errorNumber";
String evaluate = "def value = responseAct." + x;
Eval.me(evaluate);
```

Error I am getting is:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
def responseAct = [
    response: [
        errorNumber: 2
    ]
]

String x = "response.errorNumber";
String evaluate = "def value = $responseAct." + x
Eval.x(responseAct, evaluate)
```

Comment: Well, now I am getting this exception: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Comment: Sorry, I won't reproduce it without soapUI :/

Comment: @AvirupDas, have you solved the problem? Do you have an reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

@Opal, Yeah... got through the problem. Its just the variable for the JSON data should have been a object of JsonSlurper. Here is an working example:

```
def objResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Step Name for Rest Step").getPropertyValue("response"));
String res = "response.errorNumber";
String evaluate = "x." + res;
String value = Eval.x(objResponse, evaluate);
```